# Things I have tried to fix Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I have exhausted myself for the past 2 hours reading and troubleshooting the problem on the MySQL workbench.

Anyway, this is what I did:
googled "MySQL workbench"
installed MySQL workbench 6.3.9 using the MSI file.

set-up new connection and manage server connections (tried both)

Connection Name: MyFirstConnection
Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)
Hostname: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3306
Username: root

then I pressed "test connection"... guess what:
**Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root**

Things I have tried so far:

1a.) Go to "cmd" -> type mysql -u root -p

1b.) Go to "cmd" -> type mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306

Result:
'mysql' is not recognizable as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

2.) Start workbench as administrator

Result:
**Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root**

3.) "my.cnf" file

Result:
Cannot find it in installation directory at all or in search ("my.cnf" or even "my")

4a.) Search services.msc then Activate the MySQL server manually.

Result:
[services.msc panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyjm8.png)
Okay.. "MySQL" as stated is not even there.

[Only SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSioo.png)
This is the closest thing to MySQL I can find and I don't even know what it does so okay. I just pressed "reset" for the heck of it.

Result: **Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root**

5a.) Change hostname to localhost

5b.) Change hostname to netBiosName (or Asus-PC in my case)

Results:
**Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost with user root**
and
**Failed to Connect to MySQL at Asus-PC with user root**

6.) Change 3306 to 3307

Results:
**Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root**

7.) Check my internet connection

Results: Okay i'm writing this thing and publishing it.

So what else have I not tried. I just started using workbench today and is already extremely difficult to navigate through.

Answer (score 0):

You know that MySQL Workbench is only a client? And a client needs a server. Where is your server? Did you install one (doesn't look so)? I recommend the [MySQL Installer For Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) which comes with everything to get you started easily.

Comment: Okay that seems to be my mistake. Thanks dude. The website has so much add ons that you can't really find the one that you need lol